# Why is there no subject between "guess" and "getting"? and why does this sentence use "guess" instead of "guessed"?

Tags: grammar

> Mike: So you two are finally gonna get hitched. who popped the question? was it you? Matt, or did you propose to him, Allison?
>
> Matt: I decided to be the romantic one, I took Allison to the park where we had our five-year anniversary picnic, and asked her there...
>
> Matt: she was in a bad mood that day, I almost lost my nerve, I thought she was gonna turn me down
>
> Allison: He's right... I almost left him in the park. I had a terrible migraine. Stress at work. And he'd been acting so strange, **I guess getting ready for the big question.**

Comment: What is this from?  What do you think is wrong with it, and why?  Could you please add more detail to explain what you think would be correct?  Also be aware that spoken dialogue is not always grammatically correct -- it's normal to  skip words when the omission doesn't change the meaning, or it's obvious what was omitted.  In this case Allison omits "he was".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no subject because it's redundant. Alison could say: "I guess **he'd been** getting ready for the big question". But that has been said at the start of the sentence so there is no necessity to repeat the same thing.

She is talking with Mat and Mike **now**. And she is giving her opinion **now** that's why she uses Present Tense